# how to read current Url in Angular

Tags: angular

I'm pretty new in programming and my manager asked me to do something I don't really know how to do. I need to create a function that will read the URL and thus know which environment is being built. The function should then insert the correct environment in the load function,  which now has the following code:

```
load() {
    const jsonFile = `assets / config / config.$ {
        environment.name
    }.json`;
    console.log(`Loading file $ {
        jsonFile
    }`)
    return new Promise < void > ((resolve, reject) = > {
            this.http.get(jsonFile).toPromise().then((response: IAppConfig) = > {
                    AppConfig.settings = <IAppConfig>response;
               resolve();
            }).catch((response: any) => {
               reject(`Could not load file '${jsonFile}': ${JSON.stringify(response)}`);
               console.log(jsonFile);
            });
        });
    }
```

Can anyone tell me how to extract the current URL? Once I have that, my function would look like this:

```
configUrl() {
var currentUrl =
```

I would then change the load function by replacing the current const jsonfile with something like this:

```
const jsonFile = assets/config/config.${currentUrl.name}.json;
```

Does this make sense? Can anyone help me?

Comment: `window.location.href` ?

Comment: this.router.url

Comment: actually the function should first read the current url, then extract the environment from it, and then insert it in the load function...

Comment: ActivatedRoute, it's in the guide. On mobile can't give a better answer

Comment: @HeidiEigner Where do you need the current url ? in the load function ? Then, in your load function you get the current url `window.location.href`, then you parse it accordingly to what you need (the _environment_). Note that you can also use `window.location.hostname` in your case it might be more relevant.

Answer (score 1):

Use the Angular Router class for getting the current URL:

```
currentUrl: string;

constructor(private router: Router){
    this.currentUrl = this.router.url;
    this.load();
}
```

Comment: window.location.hostname works perfectly. My function is working. First function I did all by myself...in the past, I usually copied what I saw online or from colleagues. I know it's ridiculously minor, but still, feels good. Thanks to all of you who responded. I'm posting it, as there may be more elegant ways of writing it, but this works...

Answer (score 0):

```
load() {
        // const jsonFile = `assets/config/config.${environment.name}.json`;
      this.configEnv()
      const jsonFile = `assets/config/config.${this.currentEnv}.json`;
      console.log(`Loading file ${jsonFile}`)
        return new Promise<void>((resolve, reject) => {
            this.http.get(jsonFile).toPromise().then((response : IAppConfig) => {
               AppConfig.settings = <IAppConfig>response;
               resolve();
            }).catch((response: any) => {
               reject(`Could not load file '${jsonFile}': ${JSON.stringify(response)}`);
               console.log(jsonFile);
            });
        });
    }


    configEnv() {
          this.currentUrl = window.location.hostname;
          if(this.currentUrl.includes('local')) {
            this.currentEnv = 'local'
          } else if (this.currentUrl.includes('prd')) {
            this.currentEnv = 'prod'
          } else if (this.currentUrl.includes('dev')) {
            this.currentEnv = 'dev'
          } else {console.log('no environment found!')}

          console.log(this.currentUrl);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 configEnv() {
      this.currentUrl = window.location.hostname;
      switch (true) {
        case this.currentUrl.includes('local'):
          this.currentEnv = 'local'
          break;
        case this.currentUrl.includes('prd'):
          this.currentEnv = 'prod'
          break;
        case this.currentUrl.includes('dev'):
          this.currentEnv = 'dev'
          break;
        // default:
        //   this.currentEnv = ('127.0.0.1:8090')
      }
    }
```